# Linq-to-Entities working with One-to-Many Relationship and Sorting

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I would Like to sort the keywords by its sort property.
I have a one-many relationship between page -> keyword.

Question: If I perform a comprehension query as:

```
IEnumerable<page> query = from p in contxt.pages where p.ID == myId select p;

IEnumerable<page> pge = query.First();
```

Could I expect a single page record set with all the page’s properties and one keyword collection?

My understanding is since there exist a one-many relationship, I don’t have to perform a join. The Linq to Entity framework should have knowledge of this relationship, and return a collection.

So this is my understanding, so when I try to sort on keyword.sort, the keyword is out of scope:

```
    IEnumerable<page> query = from p in contxt.pages where p.ID == myId
orderby p.keywords. select p;
```

Utilizing the above understanding I thought the query is incorrect because keywords is returned as a collection, so I must perform a sort as follows:

```
    PageKeywords pageKeywords = new PageKeywords();
    Keywords keywords;

    IEnumerable<page> query = from p in contxt.pages 
where p.ID == vals.pageId select p;

    page pge = query.First();

    pageKeywords.keywords = new List<Keywords>();

    pageKeywords.id = pge.ID;
    pageKeywords.description = pge.descp;
    pageKeywords.title = pge.title;
    pageKeywords.showTitle = pge.showTitle;
    pageKeywords.keywords = pge.keywords.OrderBy(k => k.sort);

    foreach (var item in pageKeywords.keywords)
    {
    keywords = new Keywords();
    keywords.id = item.id;
    keywords.name = item.name;
    keywords.sort = item.sort;
    pageKeywords.keywords.Add(keywords);
    }
```

However this did not work. The keywords were not sorted by sort? The code above does work, however I need the keywords to be sorted by sort property. The keywords collection isn't being sorted.

I also tried:

```
pageKeywords.keywords.Sort((x, y) => int.Compare(x.sort, y.sort));
```

Which did not work.

I have tried to understand, but I am missing something? Any suggestions would be appreciable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from p in contxt.Pages 
            where p.ID == vals.PageId 
            select new PageKeywords 
                {
                    Id = pge.Id,
                    Description = pge.Descp,
                    Title = pge.Title,
                    ShowTitle = pge.ShowTitle,
                    Keywords = pge.Keywords.OrderBy(k => k.sort)
                };
```

Comment: Wow! Nice creating the object within query. helped a lot in my learning. Wondering, instead of using var, what datatype would be returned. My guess, the datatype would be a new PageKeywords object or would it be IEnumerable<PageKeywords>? Sweet code, saves a lot of lines.

Comment: The data type is `IQueryable<PageKeywords>`.

Answer (score 0):

OrberBy returns a new enumerable - it does not change the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

Also, you want to sort by a property of keywords, a page may have many keywords, you need to choose one (e.g. minimum one).

Try:

```
IEnumerable<page> query = context.pages // Pages
    .Where(p => p.ID == myId) // Filtered by id
     // Sort by minimum sort value of all keywords of page
    .OrderBy(p.Keywords.Select(keyword => keyword.sort).Min());
```

Also, using .NET's guidelines for names is recommended (e.g. properties should be PascalCase and not camelCase).

Comment: Wondering .OrderBy(p.Keywords.Select(keyword => keyword.sort).Min()); isn't p not in scope? My code above is incorrect. I knew OrderBy returns a new enumerable, then this should work:pageKeywords.keywords = pge.keywords.OrderBy(k => k.sort); I corrected my code above.

Comment: I would like to return the collection of keywords that match the page id. I don't one keyword. I would like a collection?